# How to insert first image if no others selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out a way to insert the first image of a jquery gallery once it's loaded basically.

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find anything. I have pasted the code that works so far below. I think I have to put something like:

```
$(function() {
   $(".image").click(function() {
      var image = $(this).attr("rel");
      var title = $(this).attr("alt");
      var description = $(this).attr("content");
      $('#gallery').hide();
      $('#gallery').fadeIn('slow');
      $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');

      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use .append

example

```
$(".image").click(function() {
    var img = $('<img/>');
    img.attr("src", $(this).attr("rel") );

    var title = $(this).attr("alt");
    var description = $(this).attr("content");

    $("#gallery").append( img );
    $('#gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

This will also append other images once their respective links been clicked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I cant seem to get it to work yet, it isnt showing any images, but Ill keep trying.

Comment: You might need to take the / out of the img tag in <code>var img = $('<img/>');</code>